# WordPress Plugin : Expose public-view with writing url

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm quite new to WordPress Plugin development. I'm trying to use the plugin boilerplate to create a simple plugin for learning purpose.

I want to create a "Contact Form", the view will be located in /wp-content/plugins/contact-form/public/partials/contact-form-public-display.php. And I want to access it using http://localhost/contact-form/.

My class class-contact-form-public.php :

```
function init_internal_rewriting()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'contact-form$', '?page=contact-form', 'top' );
}   

function rewriting_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'page';
    return $query_vars;
}

function rewriting_parse_request( &$wp )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'page', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        $this->display_plugin_page();
        exit();
    }
    return;
}

public function display_plugin_page() {
    include_once( 'partials/contact-form-public-display.php' );
}
```

When I'm hooking those function :

```
// Rewriting URL
    $this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'init_internal_rewriting');
    $this->loader->add_action( 'parse_request', $plugin_public, 'rewriting_parse_request');
    $this->loader->add_filter( 'query_vars', $plugin_public, 'rewriting_query_vars' );
```

But I can't access the css and js.

Does someone have an idea to make it clearer ? Be able to access my "public" part in my frontend website.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) for the contact form. And paste the shortcode into page content section.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I have to avoid to create short code. Everything have to be handle by my plugin itself. That's what bother me actually ~

Comment: @QuentinBouvier the short code will be define within your plugin itself.

Comment: Hum yeah sure, but I can't add by hand the shortcode. Or maybe there is way to create a virtual page where I can put this shortcode.

Comment: Yes you can overwrite a page content by page slug / ID. If you can create a short code then you can page the short code into page / post editor. check the screen short image http://prntscr.com/ei7tid

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to create my own ShortCode and this in this way. Thank you